# Hide "Other Value"in sharepoint Refinement search web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, css, jquery-ui

I want to hide "Other value " in sharepoint refinament web part using jquery.Please fine thebelow screenshot for the same. If i use ID "Other value every text get's changed"

[image]

Comment: Not clear about question, you want to hide "other Value" div but not able to do using Jquery. Please post your code to hide the element

Comment: Yes i want to hide "Other Value "div for all the refineries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the HTML elements in your screenshot, add a Content Editor WebPart or Script Editor WebPart to the page and add the following CSS rule to hide the "Other Value" link.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ms-ref-unselSec #OtherValue {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement to hide that div is only relevant on a few pages the content editor approach makes sense. However if it should apply of multiple pages I'll suggest that you make a custom search refiner template

Comment: Not sure which display template the word "Other value " template contains..